# Splunk Search Eval Case - Why does this eval case not work?

Tags: splunk

The following is my ideal final query to be used in a dashboard.

```
index=cdn_app httpMessage.host=taxes* 
| eval _env=$env_host$ 
| eval _hostName=case(_env=="http:abc-h123-apps-prod","taxes.sf.com", _env=="http:abc-h123-apps-qa", "taxes-qa.sf.com") 
| search httpMessage.host=_hostName 
| spath output=status path=httpMessage.status
| eval status=case(like(status, "2%"),"2xx",like(status, "4%"),"4xx",like(status, "5%"),"5xx") | stats count by status
```

It seems `_hostName` is not resolving even when I hardcode and values like so.

```
index=cdn_app httpMessage.host=taxes* 
| eval _env="taxes.sf.com"
| eval _hostName=case(_env=="http:abc-h123-apps-prod","taxes.sf.com", _env=="http:abc-h123-apps-qa", "taxes-qa.sf.com") 
| search httpMessage.host=_hostName 
| stats count by httpMessage.host
```

I'm sure its with my eval case because this works just fine.

```
index=cdn_app httpMessage.host=taxes* 
| search httpMessage.host="taxes.sf.com"
| stats count by httpMessage.host
```

Open to any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: first, you're comparing the field `_env` to the value of "`http:abc-h123-apps-prod`", but you just set it the line above to equal "`taxes.sf.com`"

Comment: second, when referencing a token value, enclose it in quotes thusly: `| eval env="$env_host$"` so any special characters are properly assigned to the field's value

Answer (score 0):

Avoid leading underscores in field names as they can be problematic.

The `case` function is missing a default clause so any value of env not listed will set hostName to null.  The `stats` command will ignore all null values of hostName.

```
index=cdn_app httpMessage.host=taxes* 
| eval env="taxes.sf.com"
| eval hostName=case(env=="http:abc-h123-apps-prod","taxes.sf.com",
                     env=="http:abc-h123-apps-qa", "taxes-qa.sf.com",
                     1==1, "???") 
| search httpMessage.host=hostName 
| stats count by httpMessage.host
```

Comment: your `search` line is trying to match the string literal "`hostName`" to the field `httpMessage.host`. If you want to search for a field's value equaling another field's value, you need to enclose it in single quotes: `| search httpMessage.host='hostName'`